# how can 2 vectors occupy a 2d plane in 3d space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Suppose 2 vectors v and w having,
$$ 
  \textbf{v}=
  \left[ 
     {\begin{array}{c}
     0\\
     1\\
     1\\
     \end{array} } 
  \right]
$$

$$
\textbf{w}=
  \left[ 
     {\begin{array}{c}
     1\\
     1\\
     0\\
     \end{array} } 
  \right]
$$

How do the combination, $$ av + bw$$ of these vectors occupy a 2-D plane in 3-D

Comment: I meant how does that linear combination occupy a 2-d plane in 3-d space

Comment: How do $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ span the $xy$-plane in 3-d space?

Answer (score 1):

Because $v$ and $w$ are [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) they will span a two dimensional subspace. This is a consequence of the fact that $av+bw=0$ if and only if $a=b=0$. If you want the equation of this plane, take the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two vectors to get a vector normal to this plane.